# ActiveRecord query without *_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 simple models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :subscriptions
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :user
    belongs_to  :product
end
```

I can do `a_subscription.product = a_product` and AR knows I mean product_id and everything works fine.

But If i do:

```
Subscription.where :product => a_product
```

It throws an error at me `Unknown column 'subscriptions.product'` - It knows in the first case that I mean product_id but it doesn't in the latter. I am just wondering if this is how it is suppose to be or am I missing something? I can get it to work by saying

```
Subscription.where :product_id => a_product
```

by do I have to specify `_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, right now you can't pass association to the `where` method. But you'll be able to do it in Rails 4. [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3da275c4396d7fad250d2b786027ba4f14344bd4) is a commit with this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an elegant way around that (as of now, see @nash 's answer). However, if you have an instance of `a_product` and it has `has_many` on `subscriptions`, why not just turn it around and say:

```
subscriptions = a_product.subscriptions
```

Comment: Yes, but there's other search criteria as well that I need to use, that was just an example.